# Full screen WebView Android app

Tags: java, android

I've created a working Android app for my project website. I'm newbie too android dev so please review the code of this app. Any simplification or suggestion to optimize it much appreciated.

Thank you.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyWebChromeClient.ProgressListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageView splashScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        splashScreen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if (mWebView.getProgress() == 100) {
                    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    splashScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.contains("?dl=1")) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Uri source = Uri.parse(url);

                        // Make a new request pointing to the download url
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
                        String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, fileExtension);

                        // save the file in the "Downloads" folder of SDCARD
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

                        // get download service and enqueue file
                        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        manager.enqueue(request);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url));
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("www.example.com")) {
                    return false;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/offline.html");
            }

        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/?m=1");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Add user agent suffix
        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(
                mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString()
                        + " " + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateProgress(int progressValue) {
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
        if (progressValue == 100) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

**MyWebChromeClient.java**

```
  public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private ProgressListener mListener;

    public MyWebChromeClient(ProgressListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        mListener.onUpdateProgress(newProgress);
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }

    public interface ProgressListener {
        void onUpdateProgress(int progressValue);
    }
}
```